# Why is the explosion showing immediately?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to handle the collision with shot and asteroid, but after the collision I want to add an explosion.

I added a timer so the explosion is going to show on the screen after some time, but the the explosion shows immediately, and I dont see the problem. This is the function with the problem in my code.

```
def handle_collision_with_shot_asteroid(self):
    for asteroid_rect in self.asteroid_list:
        for shot_rect in self.shots:
            # check for collision
            if asteroid_rect.colliderect(shot_rect):
                # remove the shot and the asteroid from the screen
                self.asteroid_list.remove(asteroid_rect)
                self.shots.remove(shot_rect)

                # create an effect after the asteroid get shot
                explosion_rect = self.explosion_big.get_rect(center=(asteroid_rect.x+29, asteroid_rect.y+29))


                # record the time the explosion started
                self.explosion_start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    try:            
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.explosion_start_time > 1000:
            # show the explosion
            screen.blit(self.explosion_big, explosion_rect)

            # Reset the explosion start time so it doesn't show again
            self.explosion_start_time = 0
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: You set `explosion_start_time` to `pygame.time.get_ticks()` and then check if it is greater than 2000. `pygame.time.get_ticks()` is greater than 2000.

Comment: Seems like you just need `if self.explosion_start_time - pygame.time.get_ticks() > 2000`? I say this because according to [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks), `pygame.time.get_ticks()` gets the number of ticks since `pygame.init()` was called. Meaning that your code is designed to show an explosion if the game has been running for more than 2000 ticks (aka 2 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should be doing something like

```
  if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.explosion_start_time > 2000:
```

Also check if the api for ticks() returns what you expect it to.

Comment: i try it but i kept getting an error so i did this (look at the question i change the code there) and i dont see the explosion at all now why is that?

Comment: @RoMMk if you're getting an error you need to show it to us and not just catch it. The explosion probably isn't happening because the error is happening every time.

Answer (score 0):

i fix it with this code:

```
def handle_collision_with_shot_asteroid(self):

    for asteroid_rect in self.asteroid_list:

        for shot_rect in self.shots:
            # check for collision
            if asteroid_rect.colliderect(shot_rect):
                # remove the shot and the asteroid from the screen
                self.asteroid_list.remove(asteroid_rect)
                self.shots.remove(shot_rect)

                # record the time the explosion started
                self.explosion_start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

                # defined the x,y of the explosion
                self.x,self.y = asteroid_rect.x-20, asteroid_rect.y+15

    
    if self.explosion_start_time:
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.explosion_start_time > 200:
            # show the explosion
            screen.blit(self.explosion_big, (self.x,self.y))
            

            # Reset the explosion start time so it doesn't show again
            self.explosion_start_time = 0
```